# PrimeNG autocomplete with object binding

Tags: angular, primeng

Currently with my autocomplete setup my input field shows "[object Object]" rather than the appropriate property of the selected suggestion.

The suggestions themselves render ok, showing the groupName and groupDescription properties correctly, but after selection my input is just rendering the object rather than the 'groupName' field like I was hoping the [field] attribute would instruct.

```
        <p-autoComplete [(ngModel)]="groupSearchText" [suggestions]="groupResults" (completeMethod)="search($event)" [field]="groupName"  [size]="30" [minLength]="3">

            <template let-group pTemplate="item">
                <div class="ui-helper-clearfix" style="border-bottom:1px solid #D5D5D5">
                    <div style="font-size:18px;margin:10px 10px 0 0">{{group.groupName}}</div>
                    <div style="font-size:10px;margin:10px 10px 0 0">{{group.groupDescription}}</div>
                </div>
            </template>

        </p-autoComplete>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Change `[field]="groupName"`  to `field="groupName"`

If you look at PrimeNG's doc, they dont use `[]` for `field` either.

Example from PrimeNG doc:

```
<p-autoComplete [(ngModel)]="countries" [suggestions]="filteredCountriesMultiple" (completeMethod)="filterCountryMultiple($event)" styleClass="wid100"
    [minLength]="1" placeholder="Countries" field="name" [multiple]="true">
</p-autoComplete>
```

I also tested in my own app using `[field]`, caused the same problem you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks, not sure how long it would have taken me to see the difference.

Comment: properties with brackets [] refers to Typescript object, you still can keep brackets if you put the fieldname as string like [field]=" 'fieldName' "

Comment: Any Idea on how to combine multiple fields ?

Comment: How to have a disable attribute in this so that I can disable the field on a condition?

Comment: I am wondering how to place an array element in form there, for e.g if we have value like { "group":["name":"test","description":"test"] } and I only want to access the 0th element how shall I achieve this